# How to implement always have "Mobile data" ON in android?

Tags: android

I have a requirement to always have mobile data "ON" in android. How to implement it through code ? do i need to register for some broadcast receiver or something like that ?

Comment: Applications don't get to decide that, it's a user preference. Your application should be able to deal with either.

Comment: Actually required is to implement preference for the user to either always stay connected to mobile data or on demand connect like in htc feature already there

Answer (score 3):

You can't control when mobile data is on.  You can only register a receiver to be told when it changes.

Comment: Actually required is to implement preference for the user to either always stay connected to mobile data or on demand connect like in htc feature already there

Comment: The only control you can have over the data connection is via airplane mode, and you can't even control that anymore in 4.2.  I'm not familiar with HTC, but carriers often customize Android beyond what you can do with an app.  You simply can not control when data is connected or not.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you need the register for CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE reciever,

You can use my connectivity change helper to do this,

https://github.com/talhakosen/ConnectionListener

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the solution could b to when user select always on: if already not connected, connect and if connected register receiver to listen for state change, on disconnect state receive, connect again..please suggest this approach is right?

Comment: You can't do that.  If the data connection disconnects, there's nothing you can do to connect it again, you just have to wait.